# Headers have already been sent - Koa and bcrypt

Tags: javascript, bcrypt, koa

I'm trying to create a sign-in endpoint for my app. I've used bcrypt to hash the password when a user a created. When signing in, I want to compare the hash with the string password. However, when I sign-in using postman, I get a 404 error "headers have already been sent". I looked on the koa git forum [using crypto with koa 2](https://github.com/koajs/koa/issues/948) and the accepted answer suggests wrapping the function in an async await, which is what I've done. I can't figure out why node keeps sending me a 'headers have already been sent' error.

```js
var User = db.get('users');
var Review = db.get('reviews');

//this create user function works as intended...

module.exports.create = async (ctx, next) => {
  if ('POST' != ctx.method) return await next();

  let user = ctx.request.body;

  console.log('CREATE USER params:');
  console.log(user);

  console.log(user.username);
  let users = await User.find({username:user.username});
  console.log(users); //why is this a function???
  if (users.length > 0) {
    ctx.status = 400;
    ctx.body = {
      errors:[
        'Username already exists.'
      ]
    };
  } else {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
    await User.insert({username:user.username, password:hash});
    console.log('Creating user…');
    console.log(user);
    ctx.body = filterProps(user, ['username']);
    ctx.status = 201;
    }
  };

module.exports.signIn = async (ctx, next) => {

  const encoded = ctx.request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  const decoded = base64url.decode(encoded);
  const [username, password] = decoded.split(':');
  const user = await User.findOne({username:username});
 
  //problematic code here...

  await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
    if (res) {
      ctx.status = 200;
      ctx.body = 'success';
    } else {
      ctx.status = 401;
      ctx.body = {
        errors:['password incorrect for this username']
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is this all code? Is there something that is triggering this function? Your error usually means that you have sent a response to the client and you're sending another one which you can't do. You can only respond once typically and in your scenario.

Comment: As usual, you can see this problem when you already sent something to output. Sometimes it happens when one of our dependencies has an error. 
Also, problem could be caused by another middleware. Content could be already sent there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was with how I was using bcrypt compare. I stored the result in the variable instead of using a callback and it worked. Why, I don't know...

```js
module.exports.signIn = async (ctx, next) => {
  const encoded = ctx.request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  const decoded = base64url.decode(encoded);
  const [username, password] = decoded.split(':');
  const user = await User.findOne({username:username});
  
  const correct = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
  if (correct) {
    ctx.status = 200;
    ctx.body = 'success';
  }
  else {
    ctx.status = 401;
    ctx.body = {
      errors:['wrong credentials']
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: If you pass a callback, `bcrypt.compare` returns `undefined` instead of a promise, and so the `await` doesn’t end up waiting for anything. Then by the time the callback happens, the response is already done… Unfortunately `await undefined` is valid in JavaScript =/